# Apache Flink write to multiple sinks one after the other in sequence

Tags: apache-flink

I have a CsvTableSource to read CSV files and write the data to S3 and after that I want to load the file from S3 to JDBC sink. How can I make the JDBC sink execute only after the S3 sink is completed successfully. The reason is, S3 is going to be used for some other processing and data cannot be directly moved to JDBC  without the S3 hop

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried so far? A snippet of your code/attempt will help users of StackOverflow help you.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you could have one job that reads the CSV files and writes to S3, and a second job that uses S3 as its source, and writes to JDBC.